# Why isn't OBS picking up my game audio?

Tags: recording, gaming-accessories, obs

OBS will pick up all my audio devices when they're set in track 1. When I move my audio over to track 2, it is no longer being recorded when I press the record button. I go and look at the video and I can only hear myself. In the image I have both tracks 1 and 2 selected, but it still won't record my game audio in track 2. How do I fix this? And yes, it picks up the audio from my game, but doesn't play in the recording.
[image: OBS Image]

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you've got the actual audio being sent to the tracks - go into Advanced Audio Properties and check your audio sends.

[image]